# Unit Tests Coverage is not displaying at sonar report with sonarqube-5.0.1 and java 8

Tags: jacoco, sonarqube-5.0

Please help me with this issue the Unit Tests Coverage is not displaying at Sonar report.

Pom file

```
     <!-- Sonar -->
     <sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>
     <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
     <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
```

I have usued JaCoCo plugin as below

```
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jacoco.version}</version>                      
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                <goals><goal>prepare-agent</goal></goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>default-report</id>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <goals><goal>report</goal></goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Can any one help me with the steps to use above plugin i am using mockito for test cases.

[image]

Comment: Did you google around? you'll find a lot online.

Comment: **Check the following links to get more insight:** I once tried it myself and the setup mentioned in these posts worked and was very informative. http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/maven/creating-code-coverage-reports-for-unit-and-integration-tests-with-the-jacoco-maven-plugin/ and http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074515/core-java/unit-test-code-coverage-with-maven-and-jacoco.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Jacoco fire off the Surefire plugin to execute the unit tests.  If you want to separate unit and acceptance tests in Sonar you can do that as well.

Here's a good walk through on how to do this (both unit and acceptance tests).

[Code coverage by unit and acceptance tests](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/maven/creating-code-coverage-reports-for-unit-and-integration-tests-with-the-jacoco-maven-plugin)